# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XX' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-4.8, microsoft.bcl

I have a C#/.NET project that's targeting .NET Framework 4.8. When attempting to do an Import-Module in terminal, I get this error:
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I've looked into whether the references used could have additional dependencies, but I think I've installed all the correct packages.

Here's the app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.2" newVersion="4.0.1.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" /></startup></configuration>
```

Here's the packages.config:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="SSH.NET" version="2020.0.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.IO.Abstractions" version="17.0.10" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.5" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net48" />
</packages>
```

Lastly, here's the .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{24A3FCA7-8C75-4638-8F98-B6A2DD898CEB}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Com.Name.Scripting</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Com.Name.Scripting</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>
    </TargetFrameworkProfile>
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>..\bin\debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <DocumentationFile>..\bin\debug\Com.Name.Scripting.XML</DocumentationFile>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <NoWarn>1591</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>..\bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <DocumentationFile>..\bin\Release\Com.Name.Scripting.XML</DocumentationFile>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.6.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll</HintPath>
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Renci.SshNet, Version=2020.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1cee9f8bde3db106, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\SSH.NET.2020.0.2\lib\net40\Renci.SshNet.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Buffers.4.5.1\lib\net461\System.Buffers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.IO.Abstractions, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96bf224d23c43e59, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.IO.Abstractions.17.0.10\lib\net461\System.IO.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Management.Automation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\Libs\System.Management.Automation.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Memory.4.5.5\lib\net461\System.Memory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.4\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

If I'm understanding the dependencies for each package, there exists a relationship of Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces v6.0.0.0 > System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions v4.5.4 > System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe v6.0.0

Any ideas why there would still be an error that seems to be looking for v1.0.0.0?

A few things I've tried:

- Clearing the assembly cache
- Clearing the NuGet package Cache
- Doing an 'Update-Package' for the specific versions required in my project

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Fusion++ Log:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (9/14/2022 @ 7:05:24 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = powershell.exe
Calling assembly : Autofac, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
ERR: Unrecoverable error occurred during pre-download check (hr = 0x80070002).



*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (9/14/2022 @ 7:05:24 PM) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = powershell.exe
Calling assembly : Autofac, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da.
===
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
```

Comment: using [fusion log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) would be useful to debug this issue.

Comment: @YK1 Added a log from Fusion++ above. Note: The log shows Autofac 5.2.0 which is a downgrade I tried to see if it made a difference. 6.4.0 has the same issue.

Comment: That's not the complete csproj file. I don't see where you specified that .NET Framework version.

Answer (score 4):

After looking into this issue more, it seems that Autofac's version was my issue. For some reason, `Autofac 6.4.`0 and `Autofac 5.2.0` were both looking for `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces v1.0.0.0`, even though the listed dependency is `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces >=v1.1.0.0`.
However, Autofac was also targeting .Netstandard rather than .NET Framework 4.8 which caused some incompatibility.
Ultimately, I downgraded Autofac to 4.9.4 as any new functionality isn't necessary in my project anyway. This comes with less dependencies and the error isn't present.